# Using yq to swap values inside an array of objects

Tags: yaml, yq

I have the following YAML file:

```
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 300
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-08'
description: ''
enableCDN: false
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
logConfig:
  enable: false
name: backend
port: 80
portName: portname
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30
```

And I would like to swap the two `capacityScaler` values, so my desired output should look like this:

```
affinityCookieTtlSec: 0
backends:
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 1.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
- balancingMode: UTILIZATION
  capacityScaler: 0.0
  group: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
  maxUtilization: 0.8
connectionDraining:
  drainingTimeoutSec: 300
creationTimestamp: '2021-09-08'
description: ''
enableCDN: false
healthChecks:
- https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
kind: compute#backendService
loadBalancingScheme: EXTERNAL
logConfig:
  enable: false
name: backend
port: 80
portName: portname
protocol: HTTP
selfLink: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/
sessionAffinity: NONE
timeoutSec: 30
```

So far I'm only able to echo the output but not sure how to swap the values

`yq e  '.backends[].capacityScaler' https_backend.yaml`

outputs:

```
0.0
1.0
```

Comment: I raised a GitHub issue to yq, after attempting an answer to this question, https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/issues/934. I guess you can't make it work as of the latest release

Answer (score 1):

With [yq - jq wrapper](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq) (not to be confused with [yq is a portable command-line YAML processor](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) ) it's quite simple, just like swap in other languages:

```
yq -y '.backends[0].capacityScaler as $x | .backends[0].capacityScaler = .backends[1].capacityScaler | .backends[1].capacityScaler = $x'
```

Comment: Thanks! that work's except it changed the value from float to integer, wondering if you had the same problem or is it an issue with my platform? (MacOS)

Answer (score 1):

The issue with swapping out values is now fixed in [mikefarah/yq - Release v4.13.0](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.13.0). With that you could just do

```sh
yq e '
  .backends[0].capacityScaler as $t | 
  .backends[0].capacityScaler = .backends[1].capacityScaler | 
  .backends[1].capacityScaler = $t' yaml
```